how to sanitze client query to whereFullText eloquent method in laravel
I'm encountering an issue with whereFullText in Laravel. Here's my code:
$search_key = $args['q'] ?? $args['search_key'] ?? NULL;
$builder->when($search_key, function (Builder $builder, $search_key) {
    $builder->whereFullText(self::fullTextColumns(), $search_key . self::WILDCARD, [
        'mode' => 'boolean', // [ natural, natural language, query expansion, boolean ]
    ]);
});

When a client sends a search_key that contains malicious payload like "asd--", the rest of my SQL query gets commented out. This vulnerability leaves it open to SQL injection. Is there any way to handle this issue?
this problem only happens when mode is in "boolean". other modes work as expected!!

I've found I've had to sanitize the queries a bit before sending them. Mine likes to throw errors when plus signs are added to it.

@aynber this scenario only happens in boolean mode

Yes, so does mine. I still need to remove certain characters from the search string before I add it to the query.

@aynber could you share your code?

As a note, it's not because of prepared queries, but rather because boolean full text queries have certain characters that act as operators. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-boolean.html for the operators. The minus sign isn't commenting out the rest of the query, but rather saying "This/These words should not match"

Mine is a bit specific because of how I'm building the query, but I use str_replace to remove the unnecessary characters.

@aynber please look at the picture i just uploaded. it looks that it comment out the rest of the query isnt it?

If you copied the query from the error message, it removes the quotes from the strings you pass in because they're actually prepared statements. If you add the quotes around "asd--", you'll see a different error message, and it's not commented out.

@aynber I found this. Is it enough for a dupe? If not (and especially if you have a Laravel-specific solution) I think it's worth an answer

@YourCommonSense I saw that as well, but I'm not sure if that would work in this case. Let me mess with something...

MySql's full text search has several characters as operators, so +, -, and * have special meanings. I'd suggest sanitizing the string before passing it along the query. I strip out everything except alphanumeric characters and replace it with spaces, then tweak it a bit more to remove extra spaces:
$q = preg_replace('/[^a-z\d]+/i', ' ', $q);
$q = preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $q);
$q = trim($q);

If you want to make sure every word is present, replace the spaces with space and plus:
$q = '+' . str_replace(' ', ' +', $q);


i have also write a sanitizer without using regex:
protected static function sanitizeKeyword($keyword): string
{
    // Define an array of special characters to be handled

    // Split the input keyword into an array of individual words
    $keywordArray = array_filter(explode(' ', $keyword), function ($word) {
        return strlen($word) >= 3;
    });

    // Function to remove leading and trailing special characters from a keyword
    $trimSpecialChars = function ($word) {
        $specialChar = ['*', '+', '-', ' ', '(', ')', '~', '@', '%', '<', '>'];
        $word        = ltrim($word, implode('', $specialChar));

        return rtrim($word, implode('', $specialChar));
    };

    // Sanitize each keyword and filter out any empty results after trimming
    $sanitizedKeywords = array_filter(array_map($trimSpecialChars, $keywordArray));

    // Join the sanitized keywords into a single string with ' ' . self::AND separator
    $finalString = implode(' ' . self::AND, $sanitizedKeywords);

    // Prepend self::AND to the final string if it is not empty
    if (! empty($finalString)) {
        $finalString = $finalString . self::WILDCARD;
    }

    return $finalString;
}

